# Prove $aX$ is a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a r.v. on a given probability space and let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $aX$ is a r.v.

I need to check if my proof is correct.

Proof:

A random variable is a function $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So $aX$ will be the random function such that $aX : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $\{\omega \in \Omega : aX(\omega) \leq x\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

**Updated Proof**

Let $Y = aX$ be a random variable.
Then $Y : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{\omega \in \Omega : Y(\omega) \leq x \} \in \mathcal{F}$. This is implies that $\{\omega \in \Omega : aX(\omega) \leq x \} \in \mathcal{F}$ which implies that $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq \frac{x}{a} \} \in \mathcal{F}$. Therefore $aX$ is a random variable.

---

**Corrected Proof**

Let $Y = aX$.
Then $Y : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{\omega \in \Omega : Y(\omega) \leq x \}$. This is implies that $\{\omega \in \Omega : aX(\omega) \leq x \}$ which implies that $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq \frac{x}{a} \} \in \mathcal{F}$ since $\frac{x}{a} \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore $aX$ is a random variable.

Comment: It's not clear you've established anything in the second part about aX. You need to show $aX$ obeys the definition. Maybe write $Y=aX,$ then write the definition in terms of Y and then show you can get from the fact that $X$ obeys the definition to the fact that Y does

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen please can you check my new proof.

Comment: You are more on the right track now, but you still have it a little bit backwards. You start by assuming $Y=aX$ is a random variable, but this is what you need to prove. You go on to show this means that $X$ is a random variable. So you have shown that if $Y$ is a random variable and $Y=aX$ then $X$ is a random variable. This is actually true and your proof is correct, but backwards from what you intended. The forwards proof is almost exactly the same. I posted a proof below. I think if you try again and compare you'll get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $X$ is a random variable. This means that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega) < x\}\in \mathcal{F}.$

Let $Y = aX.$ To establish that $Y$ is an RV we must show that for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega) < y\}\in \mathcal{F}.$

Since $Y(\omega) = aX(\omega),$ we can write $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega) < y\} = \{\omega\in\Omega\mid aX(\omega) < y\} = \{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega) < y/a\} .$$

Since $y/a\in\mathbb{R},$ by the definition of "$X$ is a random variable," $$ \{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega) < y/a\}\in \mathcal{F}.$$

So we have shown that $$ \{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega) < y\}\in \mathcal{F}.$$

This means $Y$ is a random variable.

Comment: Cool! So the errors in my proof were that in the first sentence I should not say that $Y$ is a random variable. In the second sentence, I should not claim that set is $\mathcal{F}-$ measurable. I just need to add that since $\frac{x}{a}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ then that satisfies that $aX$ is a random variable.

Comment: @Mika'il. Yes, you need to *show* the set is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Looking at your corrected proof, it's unclear what the second sentence means (You say then '$Y$ is a map such that (a set)' A set is not a statement. If you meant to say the set is measureable, that's wrong, since we can't assume it. It's what we're trying to prove.) You need to start with the fact that for any $x$, $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) < x\}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, and then prove that the corresponding set for $Y,$ $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid Y(\omega) < y\}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for any $y.$

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect since we should consider non-strict inequality. Another thing is that we should notice that if $a$ is negative, then this transition is incorrect and we actually have $\{\omega \in \Omega | aX(\omega) \leq y\} = \{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \geq \frac{y}{a}\}$. The transition back to $\leq$ can be made by considering the complement of $\{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \geq \frac{y}{a}\}$ which is also $F$-measurable. Please note that the complement will have strict inequality, therefore we should pass to $\leq$ with a limit.

Comment: @mur_tm Does the answer show that $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ and what you did was to show that $A^{c}_i \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @Alex, I am not sure what you mean by $A_i$. The answer shows that $aX$ is an RV giving $a > 0$. Nevertheless, the exercise questions is $aX$ is an RV for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Continuing the proof, the case $a = 0$ is trivial. And for $a < 0$ we have $\{\omega|X(\omega) \geq y/a\} \in \mathcal{F}$. It does not imply that CDF, the $\{\mu|X(\omega) < y/a\}$ is $\mathcal{F}\text{-measurable}$, but we know it for $\{\omega|X(\omega) \leq y/a - \epsilon \}$ where $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Then we recall that probability measure is continuous and notice that as $\epsilon \to 0$ we have $\{\omega | X(\mu) \leq y/a - \epsilon \} \to \{\omega | X(\omega) \leq y/a \}$ and so $\{\omega | X(\omega) \leq y/a \}$ is $\mathcal{F}\text{-measurable}$.

Comment: @mur_tm Thanks, but I realize now I was wrong. I thought that if $A_i =\{\omega:X(\omega)<\frac{y}{a}\}, a>0$, then $A^{c}_{i} =\{\omega:X(\omega)>\frac{y}{a}\}, a>0$, and is also $\in \mathcal{F}$, but it has nothing to do with $a<0$.

Comment: @mur_tm, sorry about another trivial question: in any case $X^{-1}(\cdot) = \omega$ for some $\omega$, and $\omega \in \Omega \in \mathcal{F}$ by definition of $\mathcal{F}$, right? So every $X$ would be Borel-measurable in this case. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Alex, could you state the question more explicitly? I do not understand what is the question.. Is "in any case $X^{-1}(\dot) = \omega$ for some $\omega$" a statement? If so, then it's not true in general. An RV is a map from the event space (from $\mathcal{F}$), which is not required to contain every $\omega \in \Omega$. Is it clear? If not, please read the first chapter in Probability by Grimmett & Welsh (freely available online, just add "pdf" into you search)

Comment: I mean, an RV is not a bijection in general. Consider $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ representing die sides and event space $\mathcal{F} = \{\text{even}, \text{odd}, \text{even or odd}\}$.

Comment: @mur_tm what I mean is that $X$ maps $\omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and  $\{X^{-1}(\{x\}) \}$ is some $\omega \in \Omega$, and $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$ even if $\omega \notin \mathcal{F}$. So $X$ is Borel measurable. Is this right?

Comment: @Alex got it. To show that $X$ is Borel measurable you need to show that for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, that is any Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$, its preimage is a Borel set. For continuous RV you have by definition that for any $A = (-\infty, a]$ its preimage is $\mathcal{F}\text{-measurable}$, that is $X(A) = \{\omega:X(\omega) \leq a\} \in \mathcal{F}$. However we only know by definition that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma\text{-algebra}$.

Comment: Therefore, you can claim that $X$ is Borel measurable only if you have the event space $\mathcal{F}$ being a **Borel** $\sigma\text{-algebra}$. So in general a continuous RV $X$ is not Borel measurable.

Comment: Note, however, that in applications we barely know $\Omega$. So we induce $\Omega$ through an RV to reals and than work in new **probability space** $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), P)$. And then we take new RVs to be Borel measurable and transform them using Borel measurable maps. It allows us to be sure we did not fail somewhere to get a bad RV.

Comment: @Alex sorry, correction, I meant $X^{-1}(A) = \{\omega:X(\omega) \leq a\} \in \mathcal{F}$ (I forgot the $-1$). And also notice, that you state incorrectly that {$X^{-1}(x)$} is some $\omega \in \Omega$. It's not, it's a subset of $\Omega$, that is $\{X^{-1}(x)\} = \{ \omega \in \Omega:X(\omega) = x\}$.

Comment: @mur_tm Thanks, so when we write $\{ \omega \in \Omega \}$, we mean a collection of elements. In such case, are $A_i$ $subsets$ of $\Omega$ and $elements$ of $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @mur_tm in other words, $X$ takes $subsets$ of sample space, maps them to real values (singletons or intervals), and its inverse returns an $element$ of Borel $\sigma-$field, hence $X$ are Borel-measurable

Comment: @mur_tm: also, the definition of $EX$ uses the fact that $A_i$s partition sample space. Is it always the case? It's mentioned in Rosenthal's wthout any additional discussion, so it's probably obvious, but not to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109759/discussion-between-mur-tm-and-alex).

Comment: @mur_tm sorry to bother you, I studied Grimmet&Welsh and Grimmet&Stirzaker a bit, but still get solutions that seem to contradict in different problems. If you have a bit of time, I'd like to ask you something. I asked 2 questions recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751584/probability-that-piecewise-continuous-x-omega-in-a-a-in-mathcalb,