# Probability that piecewise continuous $X(\omega) \ \in A, \ A \in \mathcal{B}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I solved this problem, but since my understanding of Borel sets and $X^{-1} \in \mathcal{B}$ is still not polished, I decided to ask it.

On a probability triple with Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, a random variable is defined such that
$$
X(\omega) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
1 & \omega \in [0,\frac{1}{4})\\
2\omega^2  & \omega \in [\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})\\
w^2 & \omega \in [\frac{3}{4},1] 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
If $A=[0,1]$, what's the $P(X \in A$). So I split $A$ into $4$ disjoint subsets, $A_1 \ldots A_4$:
$$
A=[0,\frac{1}{4}),[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}), [\frac{3}{4},1), \{1\}
$$
when $A=1, X$ is a simple random variable, so
$$
A_4 = \{\omega:X(\omega)=1\} \rightarrow P(X \in A_4) = \frac{1}{4}-0
$$
For $A_1$, I think $P(X \in A_1)=0$, because $\{ \omega: 0 < X(\omega)<\frac{1}{4}\}$ is not defined. \

For $A_3, P(X \in [\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4})) = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{8}}$

Lastly, $P(X \in [\frac{3}{4}, 1)) = 1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Putting it all together, $P(X \in A) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{8}} + 1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \approx 0.64$

If that's correct, what would be the probability $P(X \in A^c) = P(X>1)$? From the definition of $X(\omega)$, it should be
$$
A^c = \{\omega:1 < X(\omega)\leq \frac{9}{8}\} \Leftrightarrow X^{-1}((1,\frac{9}{8}]) = \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{3}{4}\bigg] \Rightarrow P(X^{-1}) = \frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.04
$$
so they don't sum to $1$! Then either my calculation for $P(X \in A)$ is incorrect, or definition of $A^c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that $X \notin A$ iff $\frac 1  {\sqrt 2} <\omega <\frac  3 4 $ and $X \in A$ iff $\omega >\frac  3 4 $ or $\omega <\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$. ( I am ignoring possible equalities because Lebesgue measure of a single point is $0$).

Hence $P(X \in A)=\frac 14 +\frac 1 {\sqrt 2 }$ and $P(X \notin A)=\frac  3 4 -\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ and these add up to $1$.

Comment: But $A \cap [0, \frac{1}{4}]=\emptyset$ and $X([0, \frac{1}{4}])=1$, right?

Comment: First of all you should learn to distinguish between $X \in A$ and $A$ itself. It is hard to read what you write. It is not true that $(X \in A) \cap [0,\frac  1 4]$ is empty. In fact $X\in A$ for all points of $[0,\frac  1 4]$. Secondly the value of $X$ at one point does not matter for calculating the probabilities. @Alex

Comment: $X(\omega)$ for $\omega \in [0,\frac{1}{4}]$ is a simple random variable, so $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Alex $P(X=1)=\frac 1  4$ is correct.

Comment: For $\frac{1}{4} < \omega <\frac{3}{4}, P(X(\omega) \in A =[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}]) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$ because $(X^{-1}(\frac{1}{4}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}), X^{-1}(\frac{3}{4}) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739036/38873

Comment: Besides, I still don't understand which function maps $X(\omega)$ to $A=[0,\frac{1}{4}]$

Comment: You have a wrong approach to the  whole thing. $A=[0,1]$ is a fixed set. It make no sense to bring in $A=[0,\frac 1  4]$. Start afresh and try to verify what I have written in my answer. @Alex